# How to quickly turn regular spaced points into a grid?

Tags: arcgis-pro, vector-grid, multipoint

I'm looking for a quick way in ArcGIS Desktop or Pro to turn a set of regular spaced points into a grid like shown here
[image]

Currently I am creating a fishnet first and then conduct a spatial join but I have to manually manipulate the fishnet coordinates to make the points shown as centroids. Is there a tool that creates a full grid like this? I am not looking for the Point to Raster tool as this does not create a full grid as shown here.

Comment: You can specify the parameters when creating the fishnet so that the points end up in the middle of each grid cell, that is a quick way. Is that what you mean by "manually manipulate the fishnet coordinates"? This is a slower way: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012502

Comment: I currently manually change the corner coordinates of the fishnet by the spacing of the points to move the fishnet so the points are centroids, but that usually takes me a few tries to get it right and I don't entirely trust the 'intersect' function of the spatial join. I am mainly curious if there is a more straight forward way to do this.

Comment: Why in the world would you not trust Intersect? It's been on the job the entire 32 years I've been using it. Grandma's cookies could be tough at times, but Intersect is reliable.

Comment: Haha, my grandma's cookies are always good ;) When creating the fishnet based on the extent of the point file the points fall on the intersections of the grid cells. I am not sure the point values are properly allocated, especially around the borders. That aside, the point data queried is the centroid of a cell but comes as a point, a fishnet that doesn't represent that will skew the data.